# Creating bash script for auto-mailfetching and extraction to a specific location

Tags: bash, ubuntu, email

I'm new to bash scripting and I've read tons of manuals for programs like `mutt`, `procmail`, `ripmime`, and such and still have no clue how to this script or even use these programms properly.

If someone could help me out with that, that'd be great.

Comment: and what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to write a script that checks my mailbox, grabs attachments and then moves them to some directory

Comment: You could use a combination of fetchmail (to dl the mail), procmail (to decide what to do with it), and ripmime (to extract the attachments) for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to download mail (e.g. from a remote imap or pop mail server), you need to use a program such as [fetchmail](http://www.fetchmail.info) or [getmail](http://pyropus.ca/software/getmail/).  Both of these are available as packages for Ubuntu, so can be installed with `apt`.

These programs can be configured to connect to your remote mail server(s), authenticate with your username and password, download mail and either store it in a specified directory, or pipe it into an external program such as `procmail` for further processing.

As for the programs you mentioned:

- `mutt` is a full-featured mail client or Mail User Agent (MUA).  It can be configured to connect to a remote pop or imap mail server (allowing you to read and send mail, or save specific messages to local storage), but isn't really suitable for automated mail download & processing.
- `procmail` is a Mail Delivery Agent (MDA).  It is used to deliver mail to particular files, directories, or even forward them to other email addresses depending on matching rules in a .procmailrc file.

  procmail is mostly used with Mail Transfer Agents (like `postfix` or `exim` or `sendmail` etc) but is often used with programs like `fetchmail` - fetchmail does the fetching, and procmail rules examine the headers and/or the body of each message to decide whether to save each message to a file, pipe it to  one or more other programs (e.g. ripmime), and/or forward it to another address.
- `ripmime` is a tool used to extract MIME attachments from a message you have already read. you can use it on files containing saved messages, or pipe messages to it from an MUA like `mutt`.

Comment: Thanks for the full reply. The thing is that I don't know how to write the script itself to automate these procedures

Comment: That would require multiple questions and answers.   Start  by looking at the docs for `fetchmail` (or `getmail`).  Ttry to get it to download your mail and save each message to an mbox or maildir file.  Ask questions here about any specific problems you're having.  Then figure out how to get `fetchmail` or `getmail` to pipe incoming mail into `procmail` (again, ask specific questions here as needed).  finally, ask about how to write `procmail` rules to a) match specific messages, and b) use `ripmime` or whatever to extract attachments.  i.e.  "break a large task down into smaller ones"

Comment: Okay, I will try.
Thank you for your advices and time